# Javascript: Some visitors are redirected after visiting page

Tags: javascript, redirect, joomla

When visiting certain links on a website, **some customers get redirected to the homepage**. I tested this on chrome, firefox, edge and some microsoft browser I hate. But I can't emulate the problem.

This ain't a website I made myself, but I need to fix this problem.

I had the chance to take over the computer of a visitor who had that problem. **Disabling the javascript** in the browser of the visitor **solved the issue**. but I was limited in time to investigate this problem further on the visitor's computer.

The problem seems to be in the javascript code, a scroll function that loads more content with ajax. (infinite scroll)

These are the links:
https://www.coprimmo.com/nl/te-koop
https://www.coprimmo.com/nl/component/properties/?view=list&page=1&goal=0&pricemin=0&pricemax=0

and here is a snippet of the javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  /*======================================
  =            Infinit scroll            =
  ======================================*/

  var base_url_query = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '/?task=loadPropertieslist';
  var queryString = '<?= OmnicasaUtils::removeQueryStringKey(array('limit2','limit1'));?>';

  var colsPerLine = 3;
  var rowsPerPage = 4;

  var limit1 = 0;
  var limit2 = <?=isset($_GET['limit2']) ? $_GET['limit2'] : 'colsPerLine * rowsPerPage'?>;
  var is_complete = false;
  var totalLoaded = 0;
  var RowsCount = null;


  loadProperties(base_url_query + '&limit1='+limit1+'&limit2='+limit2+'&'+queryString, loadProperties_callback);

  var is_loaded = false;
  var first_load = true;
  jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if(!is_complete) {
      var last_prop_offset = jQuery('#properties-wrap > #propety-group > .property').last().offset();
      if(last_prop_offset != null && (last_prop_offset.top - jQuery(window).height() <= jQuery(window).scrollTop()) && !is_loaded) {
        is_loaded = true;
        loadProperties(base_url_query + '&limit1='+limit1+'&limit2='+limit2+'&'+queryString, loadProperties_callback);
      }
    }
  });

  function loadProperties_callback(){
    totalLoaded = jQuery('#properties-wrap').find('property').size();
    limit1 = limit2 + 1;
    limit2 = limit2 + (colsPerLine*rowsPerPage);

    if(RowsCount == null)
      RowsCount = jQuery('.rows_count').text();

    if(limit1 > RowsCount)
      is_complete = true;

    is_loaded = false;

    if(first_load == true && window.location.hash != '')
      scrollTo (window.location.hash);

    first_load = false;
  }




});


function loadProperties(url_query, callback) {

  jQuery('#ajax-loader').show();

  console.log(url_query);

  jQuery.get(url_query, function(data){
    jQuery('#properties-wrap').append(data);

    if(typeof callback != 'undefined')
      callback();

    jQuery('#ajax-loader').hide();

  });
}

function scrollTo (the_id) {

  if(jQuery(the_id).size()) {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop:jQuery(the_id).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  }

}


</script>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to emulate this?
Does anyone have this bug to?
And what can cause this type of bugs, where only a small percentages of visitors have this problem?

I hope someone can help me with this, rewriting the code seems to me the only solution.

Comment: Is the user redirected when scrolling or when clicking certain links?

Comment: they are redirected right after the page is loaded, but there is a loadProperties() above this script on the page.

Comment: store all window.location.href.split('?') objects in local storage for sure there is something wrong with that

Comment: @Emeeus , can you give me a bit more info? why would this make a difference you think?

Comment: I eventually decided to remove that piece of code and write new code ;) thanks for the help anyway

Comment: If you do something like console.log(window.location.href = "https://google.com") that execute the code and the page reloads